# OR in Apex if statement

Tags: apex

Is it true that I cannot have OR or AND operators in if statements in APEX?

I have an object that has a picklist `Code__c`, and I need to execute some code if the code is set to either `A` or `B`.

How would I write something like:

```
if(pc.Code__c = 'A' || pc.Code__c = 'A') { }
```

Tia.

Comment: Might want to spend some time going through or reviewing the [Apex Workbook](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apex_workbook.meta/apex_workbook/apex_workbook.htm).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to use "==" for equality checks, as "=" is the assignment operator.

```
if(pc.Code__c == 'A' || pc.Code__c == 'B') { }
```

Due to the unfortunate nature of how SOQL is constructed, "=" is the equality operator in SOQL.

```
SELECT Id FROM ... WHERE SomeField__c = 'SomeValue'
```