# Error in Ternary Operator

Tags: string

This is my code snippet ,

```
string.isBlank(distributorId) ? gen.writeNullField(DISTRIBUTORID):gen.writeStringField(DISTRIBUTORID,distributorId);
```

why it is throwing me error Expression cannot be a statement

Thanks & Regards,
Ravi

Comment: What is the return type of `writeNullField()` and `writeStringField()`?

Comment: WriteNullField() function writes null value to json and writeStringField() writes the string to json if the distributor id is not null thats why i am using ternary operator to check it is null or not

Comment: this can help https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/155008/expression-cannot-be-a-statement-error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an expression:

```
string.isBlank(distributorId) ? gen.writeNullField(DISTRIBUTORID):gen.writeStringField(DISTRIBUTORID,distributorId)
```

whereas this is a statement:

```
Boolean b = string.isBlank(distributorId) ? gen.writeNullField(DISTRIBUTORID):gen.writeStringField(DISTRIBUTORID,distributorId);
```

If you don't need the result of `string.isBlank(distributorId)` in later code, write this as a normal `if` statement:

```
if (string.isBlank(distributorId)) gen.writeNullField(DISTRIBUTORID);
else gen.writeStringField(DISTRIBUTORID,distributorId);
```

or if you prefer:

```
if (string.isBlank(distributorId)) {
    gen.writeNullField(DISTRIBUTORID);
} else {
    gen.writeStringField(DISTRIBUTORID,distributorId);
}
```

Comment: One should always prefer the latter, IMO. The former gets very tricky to read when you've got a bunch of them in a row.

Answer (score 0):

The below code is an expression

`string.isBlank(distributorId) ? gen.writeNullField(DISTRIBUTORID):gen.writeStringField(DISTRIBUTORID,distributorId);`

to assign gen implementation can be

```
if(string.isBlank(distributorId)) gen.writeNullField(DISTRIBUTORID)
else gen.writeStringField(DISTRIBUTORID,distributorId)
```